# Restricted Permutations for Repeated Measures Nested Plot PERMANOVA

Tags: r, permutation-test

Apologies, for this might be somewhat convoluted.

I have an experiment examining community-level differences among treatments and are using PERMANOVA along with other multivariate methods to do this. I have struggled somewhat with how to set up the restricted permutation design, because our experimental setup includes 8 plots with two subplots, all of which were sampled two years in a row. So we basically have a design with repeated measures and nesting. I believe that I know how to do either repeated measures setup or a nested design appropriately, but not both. I'll make a quick table of factors to permute.

```
df = data.frame(Site = rep(1:8,each=4),Plot = rep(c("A","B"),times=16),
    Year = rep(rep(1:2,each=2),times=8))
```

I could try:

```
ctrl = how(within = Within(type="series",constant=T), plot = Plots(strata=df$Plot, type="none"), block = df$Site)
shuffle(df, control = ctrl)
```

And this seems to be mostly correct, however, while the individual plots at each site are permuted, blocks themselves cannot move around. How could I make it so that whole blocks could also move around, for reference, the control above might give me:

```
3  4  1  2  7  8  5  6 11 12  9 10 13 14 15 16 19 20 17 18 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
```

However, unless I'm mistaken, I should also be looking for something that could give me:

```
29 30 31 32 7  8  5  6 11 12  9 10 3  4  1  2 19 20 17 18 13 14 15 16 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
```

It could be that I am totally mistaken. Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***

I am including a solution that I believe is relevant for a nested, repeated measures permutation design. It involves using multiple rounds of `shuffle()` to first move larger plots as a group, then move subplots within plots, and finally switch between years as a series with `constant = T`, so that individual subplots, plots, and years all remain grouped together, despite changing order.

```
MLPerm = function(x,n){

Perms = matrix(0,ncol = nrow(x),nrow=n)

x.new = as.data.frame(x)

for(i in 1:n){

x.new$INDEX = 1:nrow(x)

ctrl1 = how(nperm=1,within= Within(type="none",mirror=F), plots = Plots(strata=df$Site,type="free"))

perm1 = shuffle(x.new,control=ctrl1)

x.new$index1 = perm1
x.new = x.new[order(x.new$index1),]

ctrl2 = how(nperm=1,within= Within(type="none"), plots = Plots(strata=df$Plot,type="free"),block=df$Site)

perm2 = shuffle(x.new,control=ctrl2)

x.new$index2 = perm2
x.new = x.new[order(x.new$index2),]

perm2 = x.new$INDEX


ctrl3 = how(nperm=1,within= Within(type="series",constant=T), plots = Plots(strata=df$Plot,type="none"))

perm3 = shuffle(x.new,control=ctrl3)

x.new$index3 = perm3
x.new = x.new[order(x.new$index3),]

perm3 = x.new$INDEX

Perms[i,]= perm3


x.new = as.data.frame(x)

}

return(Perms)


}

MLPerm(df,10)
```

Comment: This is amazing!  I think for it to work as I would want it, we need to add `,block=df$Site` to ctrl3.  But we can really modify this however we want- thanks for introducing this framework!  I'm off to try to expand it to 4 levels...